# Charts overlap - skip values

Tags: python, matplotlib

How would I plot this in the most efficient way?

```
ALLOC_MAX,FIRST_FIT,NEXT_FIT,BEST_FIT,WORST_FIT
10,2919643,2363084,3059065,1813777
20,717496,590656,792715,449054
30,283118,244520,280983,207911
40,173158,139927,178767,109183
50,96479,87675,111013,77294
70,55893,46203,54920,43436
100,27791,25881,27216,21652
200,8720,8629,8932,7738
300,4316,4080,4181,4066
400,2699,2646,2776,2590
500,1704,1643,1691,1656
700,848,825,848,825
```

My figure looks like this where each chart overlaps with eachother.

[image]

My idea would be to skip some values on the y axis. E.g. have a jump from two big > 150000 so I get more details on the smaller values. How could I implement this in matplotlib?

Comment: log scale maybe?

Answer (score 0):

What about using the *broken axis* feature provided by `matplotlib` to highlight what happens at smaller values?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Replace here with your data
x = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 10_000)
y_1 = 1 / x
y_2 = y_1 * 2

# The actual plot with broken axis
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.05)

ax1.plot(x, y_1)
ax1.plot(x, y_2)
ax2.plot(x, y_1)
ax2.plot(x, y_2)

ax1.set_ylim(9_000, 10_000)
ax2.set_ylim(0, 200)

ax1.spines.bottom.set_visible(False)
ax2.spines.top.set_visible(False)
ax1.xaxis.tick_top()
ax1.tick_params(labeltop=False)
ax2.xaxis.tick_bottom()

d = .5
kwargs = dict(marker=[(-1, -d), (1, d)], markersize=12,
              linestyle="none", color='k', mec='k', mew=1, clip_on=False)
ax1.plot([0, 1], [0, 0], transform=ax1.transAxes, **kwargs)
ax2.plot([0, 1], [1, 1], transform=ax2.transAxes, **kwargs)

plt.show()
```

[image]